# How do I catch an API response error with observables?

Tags: angular, try-catch, jsonp, observable

I am using Angular 4 to make an API call, a successful response returns the correct json, but a response with an error returns a 404 HTML page rather than a json response (This is wrong I know, but I have no control over it).

How can I catch the error so it doesn't stop further scripts running, and doesn't show up in the console?

My API call is:

```
this.jsonp.get(url, options)
            .map((response) => response.json())
            .map((results) => results.map((result: string) => result))
```

Comment: post your whole code, what are you trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.catch((err:any) =>{ 
    console.log("error");
    return Observable.of(undefined);
 });
```

Comment: This gives the error 

Argument of type '(error: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<any>) => ObservableInput<{}>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function and use it in `catch()`

```
errorHandler(error: Response){
        console.error(error);
        return Observable.throw(error || "Server error");
}
```

like
`.catch(this.errorHandler);`

Comment: hmm, this still doesn't seem to work. I still get the error "JSONP injected script did not invoke callback."